# How do I apply good action hygiene for NGXS actions that can allow for easier maintenance

Tags: angular, redux, ngxs

The following is stated for action naming within [NGXS's documentation](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/actions#how-should-you-name-your-actions)

> Actions are normally dispatched from container components such as router pages. By having explicit actions for each page, it's also easier to track where an event came from.

The video [Good Action Hygiene by Mike Ryan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmnsEvoy-gY) is then linked.

How does this apply within NGXS in terms of maintainability and organization? Is there a way to manage these actions more easily in the event that they change or even as the application grows?

For a contrived example, suppose I have an action that sets a customer value in a customer state. This action may take place from the login process of the user (where in this environment the user may have an assigned customer) or from a component in the application.

My understanding is that the following is not the recommended way to do this due to the sharing of the action `UpdateCustomer` which wouldn't show the actual source of where this action was dispatched.

**login.component.ts**

```js
...

onLogin() {
  someProcessThatLogsIn().then(user => {
    // Dispatch to set the user's customer value
    this.store.dispatch(new UpdateCustomer(user.customer);

  }
}

...
```

**customer.component.ts**

```js
...

onUpdateCustomer(customerId) {
  this.customerService.get(customerId).subscribe(customer => {
    this.store.dispatch(new UpdateCustomer(customer);
  }
}

...
```

**customer.actions.ts**

```js
export class UpdateCustomer {
    static readonly type = '[Customer] Update Customer';
    constructor(public customer: Customer) {}
}
```

**customer.state.ts**

```js
...

@Action(CustomerActions.UpdateCustomer)
updateCustomer (ctx: StateContext<CustomerState>, action: CustomerActions.UpdateCustomer) {
    ctx.patchState([customer: action.customer]);
}
```

Rather, it seems that the recommendation is to do the following where there are unique actions for each dispatch and then update the state to account for the two different actions that share the same constructor:

**login.component.ts**

```js
...

onLogin() {
  someProcessThatLogsIn().then(user => {
    // Dispatch to set the user's customer value
    this.store.dispatch(new UpdateCustomerFromLogin(user.customer); //Updated here on action name

  }
}

...
```

**customer.component.ts**

```js
...

onUpdateCustomer(customerId) {
  this.customerService.get(customerId).subscribe(customer => {
    this.store.dispatch(new UpdateCustomerFromCustomerComponent(customer); //Updated here on action name
  }
}

...
```

**customer.actions.ts**

```js
export class UpdateCustomerFromLogin{
    static readonly type = '[Login Page] Update Customer';
    constructor(public customer: Customer) {}
}

export class UpdateCustomerFromCustomerComponent{
    static readonly type = '[Customer Page] Update Customer';
    constructor(public customer: Customer) {}
}
```

**customer.state.ts**

```js
...

// State now needs to handle both actions
@Action([
  CustomerActions.UpdateCustomerFromLogin,
  CustomerActions.UpdateCustomerFromCustomerComponent
])
updateCustomer (
  ctx: StateContext<CustomerState>,
  action: CustomerActions.UpdateCustomerFromLogin | CustomerActions.UpdateCustomerFromCustomerComponent
) {
    ctx.patchState([customer: action.customer]);
}
```

I do want to be able to track these actions as they are dispatched so I can more easily trace them throughout the application, so I understand this approach. I worry though that as the application scales beyond just a few components and into multiple modules with multiple pages and components, I'd be "duplicating" actions with the same constructor where the only difference is in the type name. Is there a pattern that exists to manage these related more easily or is this the trade-off of being verbose that Mike was mentioning in his video? Within NGRX, the case structure seems the way to manage these though I'm not sure

Comment: You will indeed have many different actions that are identical apart from their `type`. That's one of the drawbacks of good action hygiene, but the advantages you get in exchange tend to be worth it. You can improve readability and comfort by having multiple action files and importing them under aliases, giving you LoginActions.UpdateCustomer and CustomerComponentActions.UpdateCustomer. Whether or not that is helpful depends on your specific case and your preference.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I think that's a valid approach that I'll try out. We currently have a number of modules with only three states across the app. I'll create an action file per module and see how that goes in regards to adoption and maintenance.